# Youtube API crashes when onpause

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash, youtube-api

Youtube API crashes when I am in onpause state.
When I am playing Youtube video onclick it is working fine but when I am minimizing my app in onpause state it crashes. So give me some suggestions. I never used Youtube API before so I have no idea about it. Please review my code whether it is good. if not, then please provide good 
suggestion too. Thanks in advance.

```
    package com.app.embedyoutube;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
    import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
    import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
    import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

    public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements 
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    String key="AIzaSyASLaX32-EG2Rx0EWZFPbwhuBDgsBgC6e0";
    YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final YouTubePlayerView youtubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtubePlayerView);
        youtubePlayerView.initialize(key,this);
        findViewById(R.id.b1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            play("ScQrLSBAuQk");
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.b2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                play("Ow9-fzf4Qbk");
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

            youTubePlayer1=youTubePlayer;
        youTubePlayer1.cueVideo("Ow9-fzf4Qbk");
        youTubePlayer1.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
            @Override public void onAdStarted() { }
            @Override public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) { }
            @Override public void onLoaded(String arg0) { }
            @Override public void onLoading() { }
            @Override public void onVideoEnded() { }
            @Override public void onVideoStarted() { }
        });


        youTubePlayer1.setPlaybackEventListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {
            @Override public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) { }
            @Override public void onPaused() { }
            @Override public void onPlaying() { }
            @Override public void onSeekTo(int arg0) { }
            @Override public void onStopped() { }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    }


    public void play(String url)
    {
        if( youTubePlayer1 != null ) {
            youTubePlayer1.cueVideo(url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (youTubePlayer1 != null) {
            if(youTubePlayer1.isPlaying()) {
               // currentPlayerTime = youTubePlayer1.getCurrentTimeMillis();
                youTubePlayer1.pause();
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (youTubePlayer1 != null) {
        youTubePlayer1.release(); 
    }
}
```

and you can save your current video time in `savedInstanceState`

but for better solution i will recommend you to initialize your player in `onResume` and release it in `onStop` like this.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    playerView.initialize(KEY, this);
}

 @Override
    public void onStop() {
   if (player != null) {
            player.release();
        }
        player = null;
        super.onStop();
    }
```